# Oracle query result as JSON

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working in Oracle 12.2.
I've got a complex query the results of which I would like to receive as a CLOB in JSON format. I've looked into json_object, but this means completely rewriting the query.
Is there a way to simply pass the ref cursor or result set and receive a JSON array with each row being a JSON object inside?

My query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            LABEL_USERS.*,
            ROWNUM AS RANK ,
            14     AS TOTAL
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_ID,
                    SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_FIRST_NAME,
                    SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_LAST_NAME,
                    SEC_USER_ROLE_PRIV_T.ROLE_ID,
                    SEC_ROLE_DEF_INFO_T.ROLE_NAME,
                    1     AS IS_LABEL_MANAGER,
                    LOWER(SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_FIRST_NAME ||' '||SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_LAST_NAME) AS
                    SEARCH_STRING
                FROM
                    SEC_VS_USER_T,
                    SEC_USER_ROLE_PRIV_T,
                    SEC_ROLE_DEF_INFO_T
                WHERE
                    SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_ID = SEC_USER_ROLE_PRIV_T.USR_ID
                AND SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_SITE_GRP_ID IS NULL
                ORDER BY
                    UPPER(USR_FIRST_NAME),
                    UPPER(USR_LAST_NAME)) LABEL_USERS) LABEL_USER_LIST
WHERE
    LABEL_USER_LIST.RANK >= 0
AND LABEL_USER_LIST.RANK < 30
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I still don't have the procedure. I'm asking if there is a way to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a procedure which I could use to generate the JSON, but I was able to use the new 12.2 functions to create the JSON I needed.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( --Used to aggregate all rows into single scalar value
    JSON_OBJECT( --Creating an object for each row
    'USR_ID'            VALUE USR_ID,
    'USR_FIRST_NAME'    VALUE USR_FIRST_NAME,
    'USR_LAST_NAME'     VALUE USR_LAST_NAME,
    'IS_LABEL_MANAGER'  VALUE IS_LABEL_MANAGER,
    'SEARCH_STRING'     VALUE SEARCH_STRING,
    'USR_ROLES'         VALUE USR_ROLES   
    )returning CLOB) AS JSON --Need to cpecify CLOB, otherwise the result is limited by VARCHARC2(4000)
FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT LABEL_USERS.*, ROWNUM AS RANK, 14 AS TOTAL from 
            (SELECT
                    SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_ID,
                    SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_FIRST_NAME,
                    SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_LAST_NAME,
                    1                   AS IS_LABEL_MANAGER,
                    LOWER(SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_FIRST_NAME ||' '||SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_LAST_NAME) AS SEARCH_STRING,
                    (
                        SELECT --It is much easier to create the JSON here and simply use this column in the outer JSON_OBJECT select
                            JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('ROLE_ID'   VALUE ROLE_ID,
                                                      'ROLE_NAME' VALUE ROLE_NAME)) AS USR_ROLES
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                    prv.ROLE_ID,
                                    def.ROLE_NAME
                                FROM
                                    SEC_user_ROLE_PRIV_T prv
                                JOIN
                                    SEC_ROLE_DEF_INFO_T def
                                ON
                                    prv.ROLE_ID = def.ROLE_ID
                                ORDER BY
                                    ROLE_ID DESC)) AS USR_ROLES

                FROM
                    SEC_VS_USER_T,
                    SEC_USER_ROLE_PRIV_T,
                    SEC_ROLE_DEF_INFO_T
                WHERE
                    SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_ID = SEC_USER_ROLE_PRIV_T.USR_ID
                AND SEC_USER_ROLE_PRIV_T.ROLE_PRIV_ID = SEC_ROLE_DEF_INFO_T.ROLE_ID
                AND SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_SITE_GRP_ID IS NULL 
                ORDER BY UPPER(USR_FIRST_NAME),
                         UPPER(USR_LAST_NAME))LABEL_USERS)) LABEL_USER_LIST
WHERE LABEL_USER_LIST.RANK >= 0--:bv_Min_Rows
  AND LABEL_USER_LIST.RANK < 30--:bv_Max_Rows
```

Comment: @Ali A, i like this solution but getting error: 
`00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 34 Column: 19`
for this query: 
`SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( --Used to aggregate all rows into single scalar value
    JSON_OBJECT( --Creating an object for each row
    'Integration' VALUE NAME,
    'int_id'      VALUE INT_ID,
    'Description' VALUE DESCRIPTION
    )returning CLOB) AS JSON --Need to cpecify CLOB, otherwise the result is limited by VARCHARC2(4000)
FROM
(SELECT NAME, int_id, Description from integrations)`. 

I am on 12.1.0.2?

Comment: Reddy, the JSON functionality has changed between 12.1 and 12.2. Although I would expect another error here. Can you try your query without any comments within?